# creating existing users on AWS when they don't have a group

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

It seems when chef creates a user with the id of "foobar" it also creates a group with the id of "foobar".  AWS doesn't do that.

So, when I run my create users script via Opsworks it blows up on the first user that already exists because the group doesn't.

I thought there was a way to say create the user but not the group, but I can't find it.

What's the best way to solve this problem?  Can I:

- Tell chef to not create the user's group?
- Tell chef to create it if the user exists but the group doesn't?
- Write a script that finds the existing users and creates groups for them?
- Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was due to my Chef script and Opsworks ssh_users scripts trying to create the same users.  Opsworks won.  As it turns out there is no reason to have a script to create users that opsworks will create for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually based on the operating system. Under the hood, Chef is just shelling out to `useradd` or `adduser`, etc. Each OS implements this differently.